# Stripe Payment Links With Dynamic Amounts/Auto Quantity Set

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm working on an iOS Obj-C app that will allow users to register for different events we host, and also make the payment for registration. I have little experience with the server-side aspect of anything that Stripe SDK would allow me to do, so I've been researching the Payments Link. I really need a way to have it auto-adjust quantity, but haven't seen a way to do that. I know I can let the user edit quantity, but I would rather have a way to pass in the correct quantity without them needing to make adjustments. Any suggestions for me, even if it involves not using the Payments Link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there're no params available to set the initial quantity on a checkout page. A workaround will be unset the `adjustable_quantity` param, and use [quantity](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_links/payment_links/create#create_payment_link-line_items-quantity) only, but your customer won't be able to adjust quantity anymore.